# How do I pick stuff up after I put it down?

Tags: minicraft

I don't know how to pick stuff up after I put it down (*e.g.* chests, lanterns, etc.)

Also, how do I get to the lower levels of the mine? I can never go too far because I have to push my lantern around making it take forever to get anywhere.

Can anyone explain how this works?

Answer (score 2):

You can pick up and move items with a [Power Glove](http://minicraft.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Glove).